# Get last value from column in DAX PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to get the last value from the Total column below in Power BI, and I have tried `LASTNONBLANK` and `LASTNONBLANKVALUE`, and the measure gives me 32 instead of 30. What am I doing wrong? The Date column is Date datatype and the Total is whole number data type.

[image]

Comment: provide text instead of image

Comment: Those functions implicitly sort the column being referenced.

Comment: I know,  but what returns January value of Total column, not  February.